# React Native--Functional component--useState not working

Tags: react-native

My code is:

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
      const [entGoal, setEntGoal] = useState("");
      const textHandler = (entText) => {
        setEntGoal(entText);
      };
      const addHandler = () => {
        console.log(entGoal);
      };
      return (
        <View style={{ margin: 12, padding: 50 }}>
          <View>
            <Text>Goals List!</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter Goal"
              style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: "black" }}
              value={entGoal}
              onChange={textHandler}
            />
            <Button title="Add (+)" onPress={addHandler} />
          </View>
        </View>`enter code here`
      );
}
```

I am trying to do a simple code for asking to enter some goals and to print the text in the console as output.
But I am not getting output in the console.
Some long synthetic errors are popped up.

Comment: Please attach error message in console here. we may not be able to help you without knowing your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the `TextInput` [guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput), and replace your `onChange` prop with `onChangeText`. Like:

```js
<TextInput
    placeholder="Enter Goal"
    style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: "black" }}
    value={entGoal}
    onChangeText={textHandler}
/>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanq so much...it worked!